# how to decrypt XOR Cipher?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

// The reply from server is Encrypted using XOR key = 12498
    // You shoud store this key securly inside your code. don't make it exposed to everyone.
    // You have to pass the string to XOR decryption function.
    // And the Result will be JSON code.
    // you can google for C code using XOR encryption.
    // Note: to see decrypted XOR string: pass this parameter to url: &raw=yes
    // We use this PHP function for XOR


 function _xor($InputString, $KeyPhrase=12498){

  $retString='';
  for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($InputString); $j++)
     $retString .= chr(ord(substr($InputString, $j, 1)) ^ $KeyPhrase);

  return $retString;
 }

$p= _xor("momen jaber");
echo $p;

  ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need code how to decrypt XOR Cipher? useing key=12498

Comment: Nothing because I do not know how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt simple XOR encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579363/how-to-decrypt-simple-xor-encryption)

Comment: I have texts that have been encoded with the code above and I need a code so I can decrypt these texts

Comment: A xor B = C, and C xor B = A. Just re-run the ciphertext through xor and you'll get the input again.

Comment: @MømĕnẶłmĦsĕĕrỷ You decrypt it with the same method as you encrypted it. Simply run `_xor($p)`.

Comment: oooooh thanx bro

Comment: https://3v4l.org/XshS1