# XOR RGB Image Decryption in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rgb

I don't understand how to decrypt an encrypted RGB image.

I have been provided with the key array used for encrypting the image. The instructions say to XOR each red, green, and blue row of the image with the key. Quite frankly, I don't know what this means or how to execute it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have written so far.

```
key = np.load('key.npy')
secret = plt.imshow('secret.bmp')

for t, k in zip(secret, key):
    e = t^k

plt.imshow(secret)
```

Comment: Might I suggest taking a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579363/how-to-decrypt-simple-xor-encryption)

Comment: In 2nd line you need to be reading the image `secret = mpimg.imread("secret.bmp")` , this operation will return the image as a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question of how does RGB xor decryption work, the only reason to be doing an RGB XOR decryption is if the file was XOR encrypted as applying an XOR encryption twice will yield the original document. This is seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)  and it describes the basics of what you are trying to understand